# Could someone help me figure out my css width predicament?

Tags: html, css, width

I would be more specific when asking my question but I don't know the problem to fix though there is a problem and it is the following:
My code I have been working on is all good and jollie but the width of something is slightly bigger than my page and it creates a scroll bar which I do not want.

Now before you go "Hey, it's just probably a typo and you wrote the wrong width somewhere" well it's not. I have checked it a million times over and the only thing I have worked out is that it has something to do with the body_margin div & the screen img.

My code:

```css
/*/ Font Styling /*/

a:link {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Courier New;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Courier New;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*/ Page Elements /*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #222;
}
#navbar_margin {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #555;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  z-index: 2;
}
.navbar {
  width: 90vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.navbar>li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}
.screen-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #222;
  border-width: 2.5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#body_margin {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-color: #222;
  border-width: 7.5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 3;
}
#content {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Code/Css/style.css">
  <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar_margin">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li id="nav_li"><a href="#home" id="nav_a"><b>Home</b></a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav_li"><a href="#news" id="nav_a">News</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav_li"><a href="#logo" id="nav_a">LOGO</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav_li"><a href="#contact" id="nav_a">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav_li"><a href="#about" id="nav_a">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" class="screen-img">
  <div id="body_margin">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
      <p>
        Welcome to my homepage, hope you like it.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(Note: I edited my image src to a image I found on google as a substitute)
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

If you set your image width to 100vw and give it a border, that border will get added to the width of an image. Either remove the border or set the border to 1vw and image width to 98vw - then you will have 100vw total, since 98 + 1 left + 1 right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x:hidden;` in your body tag and then you won't be able to see the overflow. Either that or resize the offending element!

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/buhuwilate this is what it looks like with overflow-x:hidden; added

Comment: http://jsbin.com/buhuwilate/edit?html,css,output this is the raw code

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the vertical scrollbar, because its width is included by vw units as opposed to percentage units, you can fix that by replacing `width: 100vw` with `width: 100%` in `#navbar_margin` and `.screen-img` rules, for `#body_margin` you do not need to specify the width because elements with `display: block` (which is the default value, if not provided) does take all the available width by default